# Verify solution to a 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, absolute-value

Let consider the following ODE:
$$ y(x)'' = \gamma^2 y(x) $$
The general solution should be:
$$ y(x) = C_1 e^{- \gamma x} + C_2 e^{\gamma x} $$

Is it correct to assume solutions of the type $C e^{-\gamma |x|}$ instead?
I suppose the latter does not meet the equation in $x=0$, because here the absolute value is not derivable, right? Or is there a stricter motivation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which domain you work. If you want a solution $y : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x) = Ce^{-\gamma|x|}$ is not a solution, mainly for the two following reasons :

1. $f''(0)$ is not defined, so that this function doesn't solve the initial equation at $x=0$.
2. Even if we admit distributional solutions (and thus distributional derivatives), it still doesn't solve the problem at $x=0$; indeed, one has $f'(x) = -\gamma Ce^{-\gamma|x|}\,\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ and $f''(x) = \gamma^2Ce^{-\gamma|x|}\mathrm{sgn}^2(x) - 2\gamma Ce^{-\gamma|x|}\delta(x) \equiv \gamma^2\mathrm{sgn}^2(x)f(x)-2\gamma C\delta(x) \neq \gamma^2f(x)$ when $x=0$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

However, if you are looking for a solution $y : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $0 \not\in D$, then it is easy to check that $Ce^{\pm\gamma|x|}$ are solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer. Yes, I want my solution to be $y : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Just one thing: $sgn(x)$ is the derivative of $|x|$ only if $x \neq 0$, isn't it?  Thanks.

Comment: @Wil  Indeed, $|x|' = \mathrm{sgn}(x) \;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*$ in standard calculus, but the relation is also true at $x=0$ in the context of distribution theory.

Comment: I get it, thank you very much!